# Is using a survey classifications plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism

I'm writing the related work section of a paper and the survey paper **X** does such a wonderful work categorizing the existing approaches in the field, that I'm thinking on using the same categories in my paper (I have already cited the survey).

- Is this consider plagiarism?
- If so is the case, how can I use the same categories without incurring in plagiarism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If properly cited, I would not consider this plagiarism, but you should be very explicit in your citation that the categorization you use is specifically from paper X. I would be more concerned about reusing the categorization if you are going to essentially discuss the same works that the survey paper has already done; if so, you are probably better off citing that paper and only summarizing what is most applicable to your own paper rather than trying to recapitulate an already wonderful work.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already cited the article, I don't understand what the issue is.  If necessary, adding a sentence like "I am using the same categories used by (reference) will avoid any issue of plagiarism.  It appears the earlier responses to your question are in agreement.